# Function equivalent of Excel's SUMIFS()

Tags: python, excel

I have a sales table with columns `item`, `week`, and `sales`. I wanted to create a week to date sales column (`wtd sales`) that is a weekly roll-up of sales per item.

I have no idea how to create this in Python.

I'm stuck at `groupby()`, which probably is not the answer. Can anyone help?

[image]

```py
output_df['wtd sales'] = input_df.groupby(['item'])['sales'].transform(wtd)
```

Comment: Hi James, what do you mean by "weekly roll-up"? Are you trying to group by item and week? Have you tried df.groupby(['item','week'])['sales'].sum()?

Comment: for example, week 1 'wtd sales' consist of week 1 only, while week 2 'wtd sales' should be the sum of week 1 & 2

Comment: Judging by the picture, OP wants the accumulated sales sum per week of each item, which leads me to think he is looking for [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, you are looking for  [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'items': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'weeks': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'sales': [100, 101, 102, 130, 10, 11, 12, 13]
})

df.groupby(['items'])['sales'].cumsum()
```

Which results in:

```py
0    100
1    201
2    303
3    433
4     10
5     21
6     33
7     46
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

I'm using:

```
pd.__version__
'1.5.1'
```

Putting it all together:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'items': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'weeks': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'sales': [100, 101, 102, 130, 10, 11, 12, 13]
})

df['wtds'] = df.groupby(['items'])['sales'].cumsum()
```

Resulting in:

```
  items  weeks  sales  wtds
0     A      1    100   100
1     A      2    101   201
2     A      3    102   303
3     A      4    130   433
4     B      1     10    10
5     B      2     11    21
6     B      3     12    33
7     B      4     13    46
```